Date range filter issue in WooCommerce admin orders list (HPOS)
I am trying to add a "filter by date range" on admin WooCommerce orders list. I am currently using the code below:
function ts_add_date_range_filter($post_type) {
    if ('shop_order' === $post_type) {
        ?>
        <label for="from_date"><?php _e('From Date:', 'woocommerce'); ?></label>
        <input type="date" id="from_date" name="from_date" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['from_date']) ? esc_attr($_GET['from_date']) : ''; ?>" />

        <label for="to_date"><?php _e('To Date:', 'woocommerce'); ?></label>
        <input type="date" id="to_date" name="to_date" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['to_date']) ? esc_attr($_GET['to_date']) : ''; ?>" />
        <?php
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_order_list_table_restrict_manage_orders', 'ts_add_date_range_filter');

function ts_filter_orders_by_date_range($vars) {
    if (!isset($vars['date_query'])) {
        $vars['date_query'] = array();
    }

    if (isset($_GET['from_date']) && !empty($_GET['from_date'])) {
        $vars['date_query'][] = array(
            'after'     => sanitize_text_field($_GET['from_date']),
            'inclusive' => true,
        );
    }

    if (isset($_GET['to_date']) && !empty($_GET['to_date'])) {
        $vars['date_query'][] = array(
            'before'    => sanitize_text_field($_GET['to_date']),
            'inclusive' => true,
        );
    }

    return $vars;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_order_list_table_prepare_items_query_args', 'ts_filter_orders_by_date_range');

however, if I select 1 date (from September 1st to September 1st) it keeps populating other orders that are before and after the date I selected. What am I doing wrong?

First note that woocommerce_order_list_table_restrict_manage_orders hook is only available in admin orders list when High-Performance Order Storage (HPOS) is enabled.
Also, for woocommerce_order_list_table_restrict_manage_orders action hook, there is no $post_type available argument, **so $post_type is not defined in your IF statement. Then your current code should not be displaying anything.
As HPOS uses its own WooCommerce custom database tables, and not anymore WordPress Post tables, there is no post type, but simply an order type.

There is no such issue as you describe: When filtering orders from dates range, the selected orders are not either 1 day before or 1 day after, outside the date range. The selected date range is accurate and display effectivelly only the related matching orders.
So maybe this is due to some other custom code added by you or due to a 3rd party plugin.

Try the following instead:
add_action('woocommerce_order_list_table_restrict_manage_orders', 'add_wc_orders_date_range_filter', 15);
function add_wc_orders_date_range_filter() {
    ?>
    <label for="from_date"><?php esc_html_e('From Date:', 'woocommerce'); ?></label>
    <input type="date" id="from_date" name="from_date" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['from_date']) ? esc_attr($_GET['from_date']) : ''; ?>" />

    <label for="to_date"><?php esc_html_e('To Date:', 'woocommerce'); ?></label>
    <input type="date" id="to_date" name="to_date" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['to_date']) ? esc_attr($_GET['to_date']) : ''; ?>" />
    <?php
}

add_filter('woocommerce_order_list_table_prepare_items_query_args', 'process_wc_orders_from_date_range_filter');
function process_wc_orders_from_date_range_filter( $query_args ) {
    if ( !isset($query_args['date_query']) ) {
        $query_args['date_query'] = array();
    }

    if ( isset($_GET['from_date']) && !empty($_GET['from_date']) ) {
        $query_args['date_query'][] = array(
            'after'     => esc_attr($_GET['from_date']),
            'inclusive' => true,
        );
    }

    if ( isset($_GET['to_date']) && !empty($_GET['to_date']) ) {
        $query_args['date_query'][] = array(
            'before'    => $to_date,
            'inclusive' => esc_attr($_GET['to_date']),
        );
    }
    return $query_args;
}

Tested and works.
Before filtering orders from a date range:

Filtering orders with a date range based on 1 day:

Filtering orders with a date range based on 2 days:

As you see, the date range is always accurate and doesn't take orders outside the defined date range.

Hey, Thanks for the speedy response and insight. I do have HPOS enabled. I tried the provided code and it is still pulling up dates that are either 1 day before or 1 day after. See attached.

Note that I removed from my code, the +1 day added to the "to date" value… From the beginning, there is no such issue as you describe: I tested that extensively, and when filtering orders from dates range, the selected orders are not either 1 day before or 1 day after, outside the date range. So maybe this is due to some other custom script added by you or a plugin. I added some screenshots.
